# How to Programatically Add an Entry to a Gravity Form

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

When a user submits a Gravity Form on my website, I would automatically like to add this user to a second Gravity form that I've created.  Looking at the developer docs, I see that I am able to hook into a form entry using the code at this link.  http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission.  I'm not able to find anywhere that would then allow me to create an entry however.  I could always use $wpdb to update the database directly, but figured there would be a built in hook to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an API in Gravity Forms that you can use to create manual entries :  http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/API_Functions#add_entries

You can use the `gform_after_submission[_formID]` hook to trigger API calls to create new entries to other gravity form

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Happens :D Even I didnt knew until I searched for it. Will be helpful in future :D